# Proof Construction on Prime Squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, prime-numbers

**I suppose that all $p \gt 3$, where $p$ is prime, $p^2 - 1 \equiv 0$ (mod 24).**

---

It can be seen that all primes $>3$ are of the form $6k±1$, where {$k\in\Bbb N$}.

$k$ must either be even or odd.

$\therefore k$ can be represented by one of the expressions:

$k$ 
=\begin{cases}
2n,  & \text{if $k$ is even} \\
2n+1, & \text{if $k$ is odd}
\end{cases}where {$n\in \Bbb Z \ge 0$}.
$$\implies p \equiv [12n±1], \text {or}\ [12n+6±1], \text{for any prime $p>3$.}$$

We now have $4$ possible forms:

(I) $12n+1$

(II) $12n-1$

(III) $12n+7$

(IV) $12n+5$

Taking the squares of these expressions and subtracting $1$, we have:

(I) $$(12n+1)^2 -1= 144n^2 + 24n$$

(II) $$(12n-1)^2 -1=144n^2-24n$$

(III) $$(12n+7)^2- 1= 144n^2+168n+48$$

(IV) $$(12n+5)^2- 1= 144n^2+120n +24$$

Factoring each of these expressions, (I, II, III, IV), it can be seen that each can have a factor of $24$ taken from it.

$$\text{(I)} \equiv 24[6n^2+n]$$

$$\text{(II)} \equiv 24[6n^2-n]$$

$$\text{(III)} \equiv 24[6n^2+7n+2]$$

$$\text{(IV)} \equiv 24[6n^2+5n+1]$$

$\therefore$ $\:$ **All** possible forms of primes, $p>3$, conform to the assertion that:   $p^2 - 1 = 0$ (mod 24).

Q.E.D.

---

I am curious as to whether or not this is an acceptable proof of this property of prime squares. I have not seen this proof on Math Stack Exchange. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: That proof is correct. There are simpler ways, without splitting it up into so many cases. For example $(6k\pm 1)^2 = 12k(3k\pm 1) +1$, with the observation that either $k$ is even, or else $3k\pm 1$ is even. This is basically the same as yours but without substituting for $k$ at the start.

Comment: The easiest way is to consider that every odd integer $x$ satisfies $$x^2\equiv 1\mod 8$$ and every integer $x$ not divisible by $3$ satisfies $$x^2\equiv 1\mod 3$$ Hence $3$ and $8$ divide $x^2-1$ and since $3$ and $8$ are coprime, $24=3\cdot 8$ must divide $x^2-1$ as well. A prime greater than $3$ is of course not divisible by $3$ , and is also odd.